# Don't exist wwwroot in visual 2017 in core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBEPz.jpg)I have a problem with core 2.1.when I create a project mvc with core 2.1 I don't have wwwroot in my project. would you please help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBEPz.jpg)

Comment: What is your VS 2017 version? I fail to reproduce your issue, try to update VS 2017 to latest version. Share us a screen shot about your result in VS 2017 and Folder explorer.

Comment: 15.3.0.but I don't have this problem with core 2.0.

Comment: Try to make test with latest VS version.

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to occur when the wwwroot folder is empty. Adding files below wwwroot and reloading the project makes the wwwroot folder appear as expected.

[image]

Comment: Your mean is index.html?

Comment: Add folder to root directory and rename to `wwwwroot`.
You can change icon this folder.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a folder and name it wwwroot in the project Folder
2. Edit *.csproj (the project file)

If there is a section that had folder add your folder

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
  <Folder Include="Views\" />
  <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If it is not just add

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

3. reload the project

Comment: after do this add new file it will apearing

Comment: I had a bug if you   from  Visual Studio GUI  it will break and freeze , now i update it Visual Studio 2019 and works okay ,